# Vertical align search bar in navigation

Tags: css, html

[image: Example image]

Im trying to vertically align my search bar in my nav, and ive tried using vertical-align:middle; but it didnt change anything, i also need to know how to change the size of the search bar, thanks :)
by the way its really light in the picture but the nav ends right above the search bar, its light grey

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#eee;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display:block;
    color:black;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

li a:hover:not(#active) {
    background-color:#ddd;
}

#active {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

footer{
 text-align:center;
}

#navform{
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a id="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Artists</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="ts">Taylor Swift</a>
    <a href="bm">Bruno Mars</a>
    <a href="mm">Melanie Martinez</a>
    <a href="jb">Justin Bieber</a>
    <a href="ag">Ariana Grande</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
    <li><form method="get" action="albums.html" id="navform">
     Search an album: <input type="search" />
     <input type="submit" />
    </form></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding this,

```
 display:table-cell;
    vertical-align : middle;
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:#eee;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display:block;
    color:black;
    padding:14px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

li a:hover:not(#active) {
    background-color:#ddd;
}

#active {
    background-color:#ccc;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

footer{
 text-align:center;
}

#navform{
vertical-align:middle;
height:45px;
display:table-cell;
vertical-align : middle;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a id="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Artists</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="ts">Taylor Swift</a>
    <a href="bm">Bruno Mars</a>
    <a href="mm">Melanie Martinez</a>
    <a href="jb">Justin Bieber</a>
    <a href="ag">Ariana Grande</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
    <li><form method="get" action="albums.html" id="navform">
     Search an album: <input type="search" />
     <input type="submit" />
    </form></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simply set a line height like

```
#navform{
  line-height: 46px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/obhh8arx/

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color:#eee;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display:block;
  color:black;
  padding:14px 16px;
  text-decoration:none;
}

li a:hover:not(#active) {
  background-color:#ddd;
}

#active {
  background-color:#ccc;
}
li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

footer{
  text-align:center;
}

#navform{
  line-height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a id="active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="albums.html">Albums</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Artists</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="ts">Taylor Swift</a>
    <a href="bm">Bruno Mars</a>
    <a href="mm">Melanie Martinez</a>
    <a href="jb">Justin Bieber</a>
    <a href="ag">Ariana Grande</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="submit.html">Submit</a></li>
    <li><form method="get" action="albums.html" id="navform">
     Search an album: <input type="search" />
     <input type="submit" />
    </form></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

First we need to understand about Vertical align.
1. vertical is mainly used to align text inside any element.
2. It can also use to  position inline elements(like span, a and other tags) vertically but its parent should have static height.

Solution:
1. Give some padding bottom to the #navbar.
2. We can give dimensions to input element. So access the input element by id

## navbar input{

height: some height
width: some width
}